# Numerical integration over infinite interval with highly oscillatory integrand

Tags: numerical-integration

It is known that
$J_{\nu }(x)=\frac{2}{\pi }$ $\int_0^{\infty } \cosh (\nu 
   t) \sin \left(x \cosh
   (t)-\frac{\pi  \nu
   }{2}\right) \, dt$ for $x>0$ and $-1<\Re(\nu )<1$.

(see DLMF formula 10.9.8)

The integrand is highly oscillatory for large *t* and NIntegrate gives an inaccurate result as shown below. How can accuracy be improved ?

```
intJ[\[Nu]_,x_]:=2/\[Pi] NIntegrate[Cosh[\[Nu] t]Sin[x Cosh[t]-(\[Pi] \[Nu])/2],{t,0,\[Infinity]}]
intJ[0.5, 3.0]
0.227508
BesselJ[0.5, 3.0]
0.0650082
```

Comment: may be not all integral representations are equal. Eq (149) on this [web page](https://www.nbi.dk/~polesen/borel/node15.html) gives the exact value as `BesselJ` for the values you used. Here it is `intJ[v_, x_] := 
 1/Pi NIntegrate[Cos[v*t - x*Sin[t]], {t, 0, Pi}] - Sin[v*Pi]/Pi* NIntegrate[Exp[-v*t - x*Sinh[t]], {t, 0, Infinity}]`

Comment: @Nasser: You made use of another integral representation of `BesselJ`. This does not answer the question. Am I not right?

Answer (score 2):

An `ArcCosh` substitution allows `NIntegrate` to compute the integral accurately.

```
Cosh[ν t] Sin[x Cosh[t] - (π ν)/2] Dt[t, u] /. t -> ArcCosh[u]
```

> ```
> (*
>   (Cosh[ν ArcCosh[u]] Sin[u x - (π ν)/2])/(Sqrt[-1 + u] Sqrt[1 + u])
> *)
> ```

```
intJ[ν_, x_] := 2/π NIntegrate[
   (Cosh[ν ArcCosh[u]] Sin[u x - (π ν)/2])/(Sqrt[-1 + u] Sqrt[1 + u])
   , {u, 1, ∞}
   , PrecisionGoal -> 12
   ];

intJ[1/2, 3]
BesselJ[0.5, 3.0]
% - %%
```

> ```
> (*
>   0.0650082
>   0.0650082
>   4.996*10^-15
> *)
> ```

Comment: Let us consider a slightly modified integrand Cosh[\[Nu] (t +t^(2/9))] Sin[x Cosh[t + t^(2/9)]] - (\[Pi] \[Nu])/2]  and the same range of integration from `0` to `Infinity`. Does the approach suggested by you work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by cutting the tail of the improper integral under consideration.

```
intJ[\[Nu]_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 2/\[Pi] NIntegrate[Cosh[\[Nu] t] *
Sin[x Cosh[t] - (\[Pi] \[Nu])/2], {t, 0, 20}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
intJ[0.5, 3.0]
```

> `0.0650177`

Addition. One can split the integral into two ones:

```
intJ1[\[Nu]_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] :=  2/\[Pi] NIntegrate[
Cosh[\[Nu] t]*Sin[x Cosh[t] - (\[Pi] \[Nu])/2], {t, 0, 20}, 
Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] + 
2/\[Pi] NIntegrate[Cosh[\[Nu] t]*Sin[x Cosh[t] - (\[Pi] \[Nu])/2], {t, 20, Infinity}]
intJ1[0.5, 3.0]
```

> `0.0650122`

Comment: I think the cutted tail can be estimated by Laplace's method or its modifications/generalizations. This is math, not Mathematica.